# Two radio buttons wether to keep the user's credentials or not

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I'm working on having a "Keep me on Logged in" state on my app. How should i do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279516/im-working-on-having-a-keep-me-on-logged-in-state-on-my-app-how-should-i-do-i)

The current codes are working, what I want is, when the user checks the radio button off. I want the app to go back to the log in screen when the user's reopens the app.

Here's the java file:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loginactivity);

        final RadioButton radio_on = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.on);
        final RadioButton radio_off = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.off);

        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("LoggedIn", MODE_PRIVATE);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor prefEdit = pref.edit();

        radio_on.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                prefEdit.putBoolean("booleanValue", isChecked).commit();
          }
     });
```

Comment: please do not ask the same question many times. If clarity is needed, edit your current question to add specific details.

Comment: Please just edit your _original_ question if you want to revise it.

Answer (score 0):

as your previous question your are too near to your solution well
try this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loginactivity);

    final RadioButton radio_on = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.on);
    final RadioButton radio_off = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.off);

    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("LoggedIn", MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor prefEdit = pref.edit();

    if(pref.getBoolean("booleanValue", "")){
       intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);
       finish(); 
    }

    radio_on.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            prefEdit.putBoolean("booleanValue", isChecked);
            prefEdit.commit();
      }
 });
```

Comment: if(pref.getBoolean("booleanValue", false)){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeActivity.class);
         startActivity(intent); ------ this is what i did, i chose the off button for the app not to keep my credentials but when i reopen the app it goes directly to the home activity instead of login screen.
         finish(); 
      }

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, when a user gets to the first activity(loginactivity), if he chooses to login automatically, when he opens the app again he is loged in and can't change his option  , not to login, because he never gets to that screen.
If this is correct, this is a problem of application design. You could just add a setting in the app that lets you change your option.

Comment: Well the user has an option to log out once he's in the main activity. I wanna know how to implement the off button from the login state.

Comment: To do that you would have to have some user interaction during the login, but that6 way that wouldn't be logging in automatically. So I suggest you make a settings screen in the app, where you can choose the same thing like in the login, if you want the to login automatically or not. Check out skype they have this feature.

Comment: This will be facebook,if the user chooses to keep hisself logged in then if closes the window and reopens fb he'll be going directly to the home page, if he logs out then reopen fb he'll be sent directly to the login page again. This what I'm talking about, minés radiobutton answerable by yes or no, if yes then the app will save the user's credentials, if no then when the user opts to close the app and reopens it he'll be sent directly to the login page again.

Comment: ok,I want to be sure I understand exactly:

Comment: ok,I want to be sure I understand exactly: you have activity A(login) and activity B(main page). In the login you have the 2 radio buttons. Lets assume that the sign in automatically is chosen. when you exit the app without signing out and reopen, you will go directly to the main page(this is the expected behavior right?). When you sign out, do you get to the A activity or does it just exit? If it goes to the login, the user can choose the second radio button and everything is ok...If it exits directly when the user reopens the app he will be signed in automatically

Comment: because in the preferences the value is yes(or true). Can't you just change the preferences when the user clicks on sign out?

Comment: Yes you're right, when the sign in automatically is chosen then closes the app and when reopens goes directly to the main page. When the user signs out it goes back to the login page if the user reopens the app he'll still be in the login page.